# Why can you read an attribute placed on a const using reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection, constants

I am playing around with reflection and by accident I realized I could place a custom field attribute on a const class variable, then (using reflection) I read the class' fields, find the const with the attribute and perform actions.  This is working fine.

I am curious as to why it works fine.  Unless I mis-understood how consts work, I thought constants were "compiled out" and all references to that constant became the constant's actual value after compiling.  If this is the case, why can reflection still see the const values?

Comment: OK, suppose the world worked the way you imagined. **How would you then be able to use a constant value defined in an assembly, if there was no metadata for the constant embedded in the assembly?** This is not a rhetorical question; I am genuinely interested in why people believe strange things about programming languages so that we can make better languages and documentation in the future.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I assume it is because other programming languages work that way, especially ones people come across earlier. I never assumed compiled-out constants in .NET, but I am not surprised if someone mentions them, because it's consistent with my knowledge of e.g. Delphi or C. Further, as people have said, some things about constants are compiled away, and it takes the further realization that you have made before it becomes clear that the constant itself is not removed from the assembly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the *references* to a `const` are compiled away - not the `const` declaration itself. Any `const` declarations are emitted as part of the IL by the compiler.

Here's an example (notice that the IL retains the `const` field).

**C#:**

```
class Foo
{
    const int i = 0;
}
```

**IL:**

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Foo
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor() cil managed
    {
    }


    .field private static literal int32 i = int32(0)    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I thought constants were "compiled out" and all references to that constant became the constant's actual value after compiling. If this is the case

I would say that this is *not* the case. A `const` is still a fully-fledged member of its class. Consider a library that exposes a `public const`. There might not even *be* any references (within the library itself) to be 'compiled out'.